# Issue with aws cli with s3 sync not copying files from sub folder

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an S3 bucket thats like this:

```
bucket_name/v1.0.0/file1.js
bucket_name/v1.0.0/file2.js
bucket_name/file3.js
bucket_name/file4.js
```

I'm trying to copy the files from the v1.0.0 subdirectory to the root directory or bucket, and delete the old files.

```
aws s3 sync s3://bucket_name/v1.0.0 s3://bucket_name/ --delete --exclude 'v*'
```

To exclude deleting the version subdirectories, but for some reason this is just deleting the file3.js and file4.js from the root/bucket but its not syncing any files from the v1.0.0 sub directory like i was expecting.

I was expecting to end with:

```
bucket_name/v1.0.0/file1.js
bucket_name/v1.0.0/file2.js
bucket_name/file1.js
bucket_name/file2.js
```

Comment: The `--delete` parameter is telling it to delete any files in the destination that are _not_ in the origin. Given your requirements, you should _not_ be using the `--delete` parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can **copy** the files from the `v1.0.0` directory to the root directory with:

```
aws s3 sync s3://bucket_name/v1.0.0/ s3://bucket_name/
```

The AWS CLI `sync` command will *never* delete the original files. The `--delete` option tells it to delete any files in the destination that are not present in the source. For example, let's say you run the `sync` once per day and somebody has delete a file from the source during the day. In this situation, the file will also be deleted from the destination by the sync process.

If you wish to **move** the objects, then you can use:

```
aws s3 mv s3://bucket_name/v1.0.0/ s3://bucket_name/ --recursive
```

This will, effectively, copy the objects and then delete the original objects.

Comment: the problem I'm having is that just doing the sync sourcefolder destination folder doesnt delete pre-existing .js files in the destination folder. I'd like them to be deleted, but not the v1.0.0 directories. The problem with mv command is it deletes them out of the v1.0.0 directories. So neither of these work too well. The thing is, i cant tell WHY they dont work. I thought of a work around  using 2 commands to just remove all files then sync, so dont have to worry about deleting things with the sync command. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

I have had a problem similar and later discovered that the folder in S3 had a space after it which was preventing the files from copying